# Overwrite Mysql table using Glue connection and spark scala

Tags: mysql, scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, aws-glue

is it possible to preform a preaction queries in aws glue job using a predefined connection?
or how to overwrite data in mysql table using glueContext.getJDBCSink?

the code i am trying to execute is

```
val datasink4 = glueContext.getJDBCSink(
catalogConnection = "xxxxx_mysql",
options = JsonOptions(
"""{"dbtable": "xxxxx.role_code_se", 
"database": "xxxxx", 
"preactions": "TRUNCATE TABLE xxxxx.role_code_se;", 
"overwrite": "true"}"""
), 
redshiftTmpDir = "", transformationContext = "datasink4"
).writeDynamicFrame(new_dynamic_frame)
```

but its not working. it ignores the overwrite and truncate options and throw an error

> java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Duplicate entry '31' for key 'ix_role_code_se_role_code' at

Comment: Overwriting data in MySQL is straight forward to you I assume?  Your real question is how to do so with glueContext.getJDBCSink?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glue only allows preactions and postactions with redshift and not for other databases.If you want to overwrite the table then convert dynamicframe to dataframe then use something like below:

```
df.write.option("truncate", "true").jdbc(url=DATABASE_URL, table=DATABASE_TABLE, mode="overwrite", properties=DATABASE_PROPERTIES)
```

Refer to [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html) to know more about spark jdbc options and [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html#tab_scala_0) for samples.

Answer (score 1):

Building off of Prabhakar's answer (converting the DynamicFrame to a Spark DataFrame using `toDF()`), you can obtain the JDBC options for a Glue connection as follows:

```
# This is the data that will be written to the sink
dynamic_frame = glueContext.create_data_frame.from_catalog(
    database="your_database_name",
    table_name="your_table_name",
)

# Obtain JDBC configurations for Glue connection
jdbc_conf = glueContext.extract_jdbc_conf(connection_name="your_connection_name")

# Convert the DynamicFrame to a Spark DataFrame
df = dynamic_frame.toDF()

# Use Spark DataFrame's truncate & overwrite functionality
# to update target JDBC table using Glue connection info:
df.write.option("truncate", "true").jdbc(
    url=jdbc_conf["fullUrl"],
    table="your_jdbc_table_name",
    mode="overwrite",
    properties={"user": jdbc_conf["user"], "password": jdbc_conf["password"]}
)
```